# Pyomo: How to update constraint definition for existing model instance?

Tags: parameters, model, mutable, pyomo

I'm being stuck on a problem, for which I'm sure there is an answer (probably a single line of code).

I have the following minimal model (which mathematically is nonsensical, but it describes my problem):

```
from pyomo.environ import *

model=AbstractModel()
m=model
m.name="Example model"

#Sets
m.mySet=Set(doc="my set")

m.myVar = Var(m.mySet, name="my variable", initialize=0, within=NonNegativeReals)
m.mutableParameter = Param(m.mySet, name="some mutable parameter", default=0, mutable=True)

m.someDefaultValue = 10
m.someOtherValue = 20
def changingConstraint_rule(m, n):
    if m.mutableParameter[n] == 0:
        return m.myVar[n] == m.someDefaultValue
    else:
        return m.myVar[n] == m.someOtherValue/m.mutableParameter[n]
m.changingConstraint = Constraint(m.mySet, rule=changingConstraint_rule)

#Objective function
def myObj(m):
    return sum([m.myVar[n] for n in m.mySet])
m.myObjective = Objective(rule=myObj, sense=minimize)
```

As you can see, the behavoir of the changingConstraint depends on the value that the mutableParameter is having.

Now when I create an instance of this model with m.create_instance('mydata.dat'), Pyomo automatically decides which part of the if-clause to use, based on the value the mutableParameter has the moment the instance is being created.

But when I update my mutableParameter now (to a non-zero value) and run the model again, Pyomo does not update its usage of the if-clause in the constraint, and still goes with the original interpretation:

```
from pyomo import *
from pyomo.environ import *

from minimalModel import m

instance = m.create_instance('datafile.dat')

# Run model once with standard values
solver = 'ipopt'
opt = SolverFactory(solver)
results = opt.solve(instance)

# Change the mutableParameter and run the model again
for t in instance.mySet:
    instance.mutableParameter[t] = 99

# --> This is where I seem to be missing some call to update the instance. I've tried instance.preprocess(), that didn't work <--
results = opt.solve(instance)
```

What do I have to do to tell Pyomo "re-read the model file and re-assess all if-clauses, based on the new values of the mutableParameters"?

I have a dummy way of doing it: Writing a new .dat-File with the new parameters, and making a completely new instance via another create_instance() call. But that requires me to write a new .dat file for every alteration in any of my mutable parameters. I'm sure there is a smarter way of doing this.

I'd be thankful for any hints. Thanks!

Comment: The rule with the if-statement is only fired once during the constraint construction. I can't remember if `.reconstruct()` is still recommended usage, but I work mostly with ConcreteModels, which I find easier to manipulate in these ways than AbstractModels.

Comment: Thank you Qi Chen, your comment pointed me the right way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out, credit goes to Qi Chen for pointing me the right way.

What needs to be done, is to reconstruct the *constraint* before evaluating the model again, but not the entire model.

Beforehand, I was trying

```
instance.reconstruct()
```

before calling the opt.solve() again. That did not work. What actually needs to be done is reconstruct the constraint itself via

```
instance.changingConstraint.reconstruct()
```

which then re-evaluates the if-clause in the constraint, based on the new values of the mutable parameter.